# glTranslate error in simple JOGL program

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to create a simple JOGL program, and have run into a problem. I just imported all of the necessary packages into my class file, however now, every time I use the glTranslate function, it is being flagged red as an error, for example at the end of this block of code.

```
public void lab2a(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL gl = drawable.getGL();
    gl.glTranslatef(-1.0f, -1.0f, -6f);

    // Drawing first rectangle (blue)
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);   // sets color to blue
    gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);   //Top left vertice
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    //Top right vertice
    gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);  //Bottom left vertice
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);   //Bottom right vertice
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glTranslate(1.1f, 0f, 0f);
```

The flag reads: "cannot find symbol", and is present for each use of glTranslate I use. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what your point is. You are using `glTranslatef` above correctly. It's either `glTranslatef` of `glTranslated` not `glTranslate`

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is obsolete, it uses JOGL 1 whose maintenance was stopped in 2010.

Please switch to JOGL 2, go to [jogamp.org](http://jogamp.org). Replace GL.GL_QUADS by GL2.GL_QUADS, replace GL gl = drawable.getGL() by GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(), etc... Look at the API documentation [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/).

Comment: I don't know about JOGL, but `GL_QUADS` is deprecated in the OpenGL Core Profile. So if you don't want to rely on legacy features, it shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: I assume that the original poster wants to use the backward compatible profile, which still supports GL_QUADS. Personally, I prefer using only triangles even though it is slower on lots of old graphics cards still supporting GL_QUADS.